# Xcode 5 Error with build Core Plot

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, core-plot

I get the following error when building `coreplot`

I need to build it alone.  It will not build in the main program because it can't find the `corplug.a` file.

After fixing the code sign error, here is the build error:

```
error: Unable to create directory: /var/folders/__/f82wk8_171q1xxdv7vpsh9cr0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/5.0.2-5A3005
(File name too long)
```

Comment: i downloaded the zip file from the git repo

Comment: https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot

Comment: Are you trying to build a stand-alone static library or integrate the Core Plot project into your app project?